# Postgres tablespace on mounted usb

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces

I've got postgres 9.1 running on raspbian installed with apt-get.
I've got NTFS usb HDD mounted in /mnt/usb.
What I'd like to achieve is to create a tablespace pointing to /mnt/usb/postgres so I invoke:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE usbwd LOCATION '/mnt/usb/postgres';
```

and I get:

> could not set permissions on directory "/mnt/usb/postgres": Operation
>   not permitted

which is understandable since the manual states that the target directory has to be empty (it is in my case) and owned by postgres linux user. That's what I have problem with and

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /mnt/usb/postgres
```

changes nothing, meaning the ownership does not change. The /mnt/usb/postgres is owned by pi user, and I need to have it owned by postgres user. The /mnt/usb is also owned by pi user.
What am I missing ?

Comment: Ok I've got it. The ownership is for the whole mount point. I need to think of some other solution.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL won't run off NTFS on Linux. Format the drive as ext4.

Frankly, putting a database on a USB key on a tablespace isn't usually a great idea. The tablespace is unreadable without the rest of the database, and the rest of the database is useless without the tablespace. So you're creating a fragile system with two points of failure.

It's a *much* better idea to instead *move the whole PostgreSQL data directory* onto the USB drive.